# How to add echo inside function

Tags: bash, terminal, function, echo, macos

I am decently new to the terminal. I am currently trying to make a small function in my .bash_profile that would send a message to a specific contact from the terminal (without opening the Messages app). My goal is to be able to send a message using the 'reply "insert message"' command to the specific contact that is placed in the function. I have been trying to fiddle around with echo since I know it can insert a text but I found no luck. I don't know where to put it in the function so that I am able to insert only the message.

```
function reply() {
        osascript -e 'tell application "Messages" to send "insert message" to buddy "insert contact"'
        }
```

In simple terms. I do know that the

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Messages" to send "insert message" to buddy "insert contact"'
```

command works since I tried it on the terminal. But I had to manually move my cursor to the 'insert message' and the 'insert contact' which is why I am trying to make it a function or an alias to speed up the process.

I'll try my best to respond to any questions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: (This question had a -1. Please comment if you downvote a question! Even more so when someone with 248k score provides an answer to this question.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to give your function two command line arguments, the message and the name of the person to send the message to:

```
reply myFriend002 'Hello, wanna play tag?'
```

When your function is called in this way, the string `myFriend002` will be available in `$1` in the function, and the string `Hello, wanna play tag?` would be available in `$2`. The variables `$1` and `$2` are called the first two *positional parameters*.

You may then use these two variables in your function like so:

```
reply () {
    osascript -e 'tell application "Messages" to send "'"$2"'" to buddy "'"$1"'"'
}
```

The weird quoting around `$1` and `$2` is for breaking out of the single quoted string, double quoting the expansion of each variable, and then continuing the single quoted string.

You could also use

```
reply () {
    osascript -e "tell application \"Messages\" to send \"$2\" to buddy \"$1\""
}
```

... which may be easier to read.

Or, if you want to be fancy, create the value for the `-e` option of `osascript` separately first:

```
reply () {
    local script

    printf -v script \
        'tell application "Messages" to send "%s" to buddy "%s"' "$2" "$1"

    osascript -e "$script"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been very helpful and works perfectly. Just to clarify, the use of the 'echo' command does not have to be placed, and simply adding the first two positional parameters would already replace the text I write after the 'reply'? Or is the 'echo' command being used but the first two positional parameters is another form to write it?

Comment: @Francesco You can forget about the `echo` command in relation to this particular issue. I have shown how you can write the function as well as how to call it. Those are all the puzzle pieces that you need to solve this specific issue. `echo` is used to produce output. This is not needed here.